# Open VPN in Ubuntu; is there a GUI for it?

Tags: networking, unity, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm using proton VPN. I have to switch to other countries to get better connection. I don't want to use any third party apps, I need to rely on Open VPN.

However,  `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` has a very poor interface. I have to open the tray icon and press **ON** on some connection I want. However if I press **ON** into another, they'll both stay on, and I have no way of knowing which one is active. Also, if I tap **ON** without wanting, I have to wait several seconds before I can turn it off.

Also, if I turn some connection off, the tray app will close and I have to go on the tray icon, open it again, and then I can connect to a new place. It's very annoying.

Also, I want to add tens of connections, so the tray applet will get too big for it.

I'd like a GUI window app where I can click on one connection and it automaitcally closes the others for me and connect to it. Is there a way?

Comment: If you want to do more than simply turning on or off for a vpn connection, select VPN Settings from the tray instead.

Comment: @BernardWei is there a way to create a shortcut to the GUI that opens when I click VPN settings?